# html add space before tag

Tags: html, whitespace

I am trying to add space before an input tag, and I noticed that Chrome didn't render the whitespace. What can I do to add a space. My code is very straightforward:

```
    Q: <input type="text" id="q">
```

notice the space between Q: and the  tag. I will use JS if I absolutely have to, but pure HTML is much better.

Comment: You should use double quote instead of single quote for HTML attribute (for validation). Your HTML code should be like this: `<input type="text" id="q">`

Comment: Note: For ids and classes, do use meaningful names as it would help you when you are coding. (clarity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add margin-left into you `#q`,

```
#q{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `&nbsp;`.

```
Q:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="q">
```

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your line of code into my html document, and it didn't work. Is that not compatible with chrome, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Both `Q: <input…` and `Q:&nbsp;<input…` produce one space's width of whitespace on Chrome 51 for me. Are you sure there isn't something in your CSS that's interfering with this?

Comment: @JeremiahMegal No css is stopping it, and I also have chrome 51.

Comment: Do either of the solutions render correctly in this JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/81cuhavh/

Comment: The &nbsp; doesn't do anything in it. It isn't any different than when I put a couple hundred spaces where &nbsp; would be.

Comment: So you're saying neither of those have any whitespace between the `:` and the input box? Both of them have one space's width for me.

Comment: No. I didn't get any whitespace from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a regular line whitespacing you can use `<br>`
but if you mean the literal whitespace before the the input box, you can use a `margin` tag to give it more space.

E.g.

```
 #q{
        margin-left:10px;
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but is there a way to make the size 1 space character? 10px on a mobile phone is much different than 10px on a huge desktop.

Comment: @Lincoln For responsive websites, do use CSS media queries to achieve that. Do google with w3schools as it is a great learning resouce. Read here to learn CSS media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp Other than that, you can use `%` or `em`  instead of `px`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the two example of having a whitespace before your input tag. It's either using `&nbsp` or `css`. Using css is more neat for me in which you can easily change it's styles. Example below css with one character space.

```css
#q1 {
  margin-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<label for="q">Q:</label>&nbsp; <!-- using a space -->
<input type="text" name="q" id="q">

<br />

<label for="q1">Q:</label><!-- using css -->
<input type="text" name="q1" id="q1">
```